# Parallelizing remote tar and getting output by ssh pipe

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tar, gnu-parallel

I've tried to parallelize script I'm using, but so far GNU Parallel is very challenging.

I've got 2 files - one containing hosts on which to run command and second having params for command. Below is sample data:

```
$ cat workers.host 
foo@192.168.0.7
bar@192.168.0.8
jerry@192.168.0.9
tom@192.168.0.21



$ cat paths
/usr/local/jar/x/y/ jarxy
/usr/local/jar/z/y/ jarzy
/usr/local/jar/y/y/ jaryy
/usr/local/far/x/y/ farxy
/usr/local/jaz/z/z/ jazzz
/usr/local/mu/txt/ana/ acc01
/usr/local/jbr/x/y/ accxy
```

And to process that, I use following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Run this on 192.168.130.10";

DATA=`date +%F`
DDAY=`date +%u`
DOMBAC='nice tar cpzf'

readarray -t hosts < workers.host

len=${#hosts[@]};
processed=0;

while read -r -a line; do

  let hostnum=processed%len;

  ssh ${hosts[$hostnum]} -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa "$DOMBAC - ${line[0]}" > "/data/backup/$DDAY/${line[1]}_${DATA}_FULL.tgz"

  let processed+=1;
done < paths
```

This works well, however processes step-by-step on machine after machine. Hosts are quite overpowered and network isn't a problem here, so I wanted to parallelize this as much as possible. For example run 4 instances of tar command on each host and pipe output through ssh into properly named file. I am completely lost with parallel `--results` `--sshloginfile`... And what I ultimately try to accomplish is to have 4 jobs running on each host, each and every one with different params (so that for example host 2 doesn't overwrite what host 1 already did). Can this be done in GNU Parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know how to extract multiple arguments from a single line of input:

```
cat paths | parallel --colsep ' ' echo {2} == {1}
```

(I note that some of the {2} can be generated from {1}. If that is always the case, you might want to look into {= =}; but that is a story for another question).

To run jobs remotely you use `-S`:

```
cat paths | parallel --colsep ' ' -S server echo {2} == {1}
```

To control how many jobs are run on a remote server use `-j`:

```
cat paths | parallel --colsep ' ' -j4 -S server echo {2} == {1}
```

To get the output stored locally `--return --cleanup` can be used:

```
cat paths | parallel --return {2} --cleanup --colsep ' ' -j4 -S server echo {2} == {1} '>' {2}
```

As you want the output stored in a different dir locally, you will need to use the /./ trick:

```
cat paths | parallel --return my/local/dir/./{2} --cleanup --colsep ' ' -j4 -S server echo {2} == {1} '>' {2}
```

To use a special `ssh` command use `--ssh`:

```
parallel --ssh "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -lroot" --return {2} --cleanup --colsep ' ' -j4 -S server echo {2} == {1} '>' {2}
```

To run on multiple servers, use `--slf` instead of `-S`:

```
parallel --slf hosts.txt --ssh "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -lroot" --return {2} --cleanup --colsep ' ' -j4 echo {2} == {1} '>' {2}
```

So in total your command could look like this:

```
parallel --slf hosts.txt --ssh "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -lroot" --return /data/backup/$DDAY/./{2}_${DATA}_FULL.tgz --cleanup --colsep ' ' -j4 "$DOMBAC - {1} > {2}_${DATA}_FULL.tgz"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow comments do not lend itself towards code sharing and discussion ;) Anyway - I need to try Your solution. My current (crude one) relies on two things:
`parallel -j${JOBS} --link ./do_on_hosts.sh {1} {2} "$DATA" "$DDAY" :::: workers.host :::: to_backup.path`
and in do_on_hosts.sh:
`ssh $1 "${REMOTE_CMD} ${arr[0]}"> ${LOCAL_STORAGE_PATH}${DDAY}/${arr[1]}_${DATA}_FULL.tgz`
I wonder how that compares to Yours... need another round to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use parallel to accomplish this, but I think it would be overkill for what you are trying to accomplish. Instead I would simply use background jobs to run these commands (close to) simultaneously.

To accomplish this with a minimum of changes to your existing script, all we need to do is background each task as it run (using the & operator to do this). In order to prevent orphaned processes, we should make sure that the script doesn't exit until all jobs have finished, which is accomplished with the bash builtin `wait`. The jobs command will output a list of running tasks (may not be all of them, some may have already finished before you hit that spot depending on execution time).

I'm also not sure on why you are using the nice command without an argument - I believe that without an argument all it will do is print the relative priority of the launched task, which I suppose could be your intent.

Here is a modified version of your script with these changes

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Run this on 192.168.130.10";

DATA=`date +%F`
DDAY=`date +%u`
DOMBAC='nice tar cpzf'

readarray -t hosts < workers.host

len=${#hosts[@]};
processed=0;

while read -r -a line; do

  let hostnum=processed%len;

  ssh ${hosts[$hostnum]} -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa "$DOMBAC - ${line[0]}" > "/data/backup/$DDAY/${line[1]}_${DATA}_FULL.tgz" &

  let processed+=1;
done < paths
jobs
wait
```

Comment: Hi! I've managed to parallelize this using gnu parallel, however I need to wait to ensure my solution works properly. In comment to proposed solution - well, that's actually why I need GNU Parallel - otherwise worker hosts would be spammed with tasks and would be unable to finish. Imagine that hosts file has more like 4-8 entries, but paths has 10-20 thousands paths. As for `nice` - without args it changes niceness from 0 to 10 :)

Comment: I was looking at the man page for nice http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nice.1.html

Comment: Post Your solution using parallel if you can so that if anyone else searches for this they find it